# Unable to access database table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am unable to access a database table in rails. I am using ruby 1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) and Rails 2.2.2

```
"ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? Modelname.table_name"   returns true
"ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? Modelname"        returns false
```

When i say Modelname.create i am getting the "ORA-02289: sequence does not exist" error message.My model class looks like the below one.

```
class Modelname < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I have created the table using sql statement instead of migration. Can anyone please let me know why i am facing this problem.

Comment: You should clearly mention you are using Oracle, which is a bit of an exception. Which gems are you using to connect to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expectation of Rails is that your model table name is pluralized (because it stores more that one entity), your model name is singularized. You may override that like explained in the [API of ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-table_name) by using the following:

```
class Modelname < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "modelname" ## if that is your name of the table
end
```

It was not clear from your question what your table name is.

Comment: My model name is FailedPayment and the table name is failed_payments. Setting the table name as mentioned above also does not solve the problem